# Python scrapy, how to only get immediate children

Tags: python, html, css-selectors, scrapy

so i have some html like this

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="infobox">
        <p> text </p>
        <p> more text </p>
    </div>
    <p> text again </p>
    <p> even more text </p>
</div>
```

And i am using this selector `'.content p::text'` i thought this would only get me the immediate children, so i wanted it to extract "text again" and "even more text" but it's also getting the text from the paragraphs inside the other div, how can i prevent this from happening, i only want text from the paragraphs that are the immediate children of the div with the class .content

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scrapy uses an extended set of [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) and [XPath selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath). In your case, you're using CSS selectors. The CSS relationship selector you want is `>` denoting a parent/child relationship, as in: `.content > p::text`. Scrapy's selectors are described in the section titled "[Selectors](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html)" in its documentation.

Answer (score 1):

to get the child: div>p  ( text, more text )
In your case to get what you need: div+p

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp 
Worth reading